# while calling a webservice from the code,it gives a illegal characters in path error

Tags: c#, web-services, command-line-arguments

I am calling a webservice function from a static class....
the code looks like below:

```
  public static class ERPBOServiceHandler {
    private static ERPBOService _service = new ERPBOService();
    private static bool _connected = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// Connect to the ERPBO WebService to access all WebService methods
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url">The URL of the webservice to connect to.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns true if the web service connection succeded, else false.</returns>
    public static bool Connect(string url) {
           try {
          _service.Url = url;
        _service.Discover();
        _connected = true;
        return true;
      } catch (Exception exc) {
        ERPLog.LogException("ERPBOServiceHandler.Connect", exc);
        //discover failed, maening that we failed to contact the web service. So Web Service is not connected.
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error while connecting to webservice\nTrying to connect to: " + url + "\n\n" + exc.ToString());
        _connected = false;
        ERPEngine.SetStatus(false);
        return false;
      }
    }
}
```

I am trying to connect to the webservice using this static class....this works fine when i am opening the application with proper GUI....but if i try to call the application using commandline parameters and then use this webservice class it gives illegal charcters in path error.

I tried getting the url being passed in a messagebox and it seems path is fine.
Note: i am getting the path for webservice from a settings file written in xml.
and path is defined like this :

```
<ERPBOWebServicePath>http://localhost:4744/ERPBOService.asmx</ERPBOWebServicePath>
```

Is something wrong when i call this using commandline params..

Answer (score 0):

solved the issue.problem was with me using nested static constructors.